# I am hosting a discord.py bot on Heroku Git and it wont go online on the discord server even though I turned it on in the website

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, discord.py

My code is and my main problem is that when I turn the worker on in Heroku it is not online in discord. I know this may seem like a duplicate but the answers to the other questions are not working for me. :

```
import discord, os, time
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import tasks, commands


TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"RoleCheck has connected to {client.guilds[0].name}")
    global channel
    channel = client.guilds[0].get_channel(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    newRole = next(role for role in after.roles if role not in before.roles)
    if newRole.name == "1":
        print(f"IGN:{after.nick} \nDiscord:{after.name}")
        global msg
        msg = await channel.send(f"IGN:{after.nick} \nDiscord:{after.name}")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("!comment"):
        _content = "Comment: " + msg.content + '\n' + message.content[8:]
        await msg.edit(content=_content)
    elif message.content.startswith("!help"):
        await channel.send("---RoleCheck--- \n!comment - will add a comment on the last message with whatever you write after\n !help = will show the help screen\n Made with python and the discord.py API by xxxxxxxx")
client.run(TOKEN)


Procflile:
worker: python bot.py

requirements.txt:
discord.py==1.4.1
```

Comment: What do the logs say? If you are using the Heroku CLI use `heroku --logs`

Comment: After looking at logs a saw that I had a import I did not include in my requirements.txt. It was an old import that I no longer used so I removed it (dotenv). Thanks! Post it as an answer and I will check it!

Comment: Glad you got it to work, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP was missing an import in their `requirements.txt`. Heroku logs are very helpful in determining the cause of your error. If you are using the Heroku CLI you can check your logs using `heroku logs`, alternatively you can check your logs on the website by clicking on your app > More > View logs.